# How to dynamically update image url from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, webforms, code-behind

I have this page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:Image id="imgLogo" runat="server" />

   <div class="content">
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="scrptMan" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updChooser" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <h3>Company name</h3>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCompany" runat="server" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddCompany_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                <h3>Year</h3>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddYear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddYear_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltAdvice" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <strong><asp:Literal ID="ltYear" runat="server"></asp:Literal></strong>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlNext" runat="server" Visible="false">
                    <div class="submit">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnNext_OnClick"/>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to dynamically update logo image from Code behind, if user choose company, like this

```
    private void FillLogo(int companyId)
    {
        //temporary

        byte[] logo = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\temp\images\baseLogo.png");

        if (clientId > 0 && File.Exists(@"D:\temp\images\companies\" + companyId + ".png"))
        {
            logo = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\temp\images\companies\" + companyId+ ".png");
        }

        imgLogo.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(logo);
    }
```

I call this method and in ddCompany_OnSelectedIndexChanged method, and in OnPreRender method with correct company id, but logo the first time is loaded and with any changes in ddCompany does not updates.
It is possible to implement at all?

Answer (score 0):

it could be because your image control is not inside the update panel. the point of the panel is to only update a portion of the page -> whatever is inside it.

try moving the image control inside the update panel, or possibly there's a setting you can add to the update panel...'conditional'? or maybe the opposite, not sure right now. see if it works with the image inside the panel first.

[wondering: can you not just do `imgLogo.ImageUrl = @"D:\temp\images\companies\" + companyId+ ".png";`]